# Why client socket take localhost as parameter?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I study socket programming, and the example in the book shows:

```
// SimpleClient.java: A simple client program.
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class SimpleClient {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // Open your connection to a server, at port 1254
    Socket s1 = new Socket(“localhost”,1254);
    // Get an input file handle from the socket and read the input
    InputStream s1In = s1.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s1In);
    String st = new String (dis.readUTF());
    System.out.println(st);
    // When done, just close the connection and exit
    dis.close();
    s1In.close();
    s1.close();
  }
}
```

My question is that, at line new Socket("localhost",1254), why the address is localhost, instead of the server's IP address?

Comment: Because the server must be running in the localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular program it's hard to say exactly *why*. The usual reason is because the server may not even have another IP address. If it's local, then accessing it through `"localhost"` or `"127.0.0.1"` is guaranteed to work even if you have no NICs at all.

Another possible reason is security. Your machine may have multiple NICs, but the server may be configured to only listen on the loopback interface and therefore accept only local connections. If it isn't intended for external use at all, this is usually the best thing to do because the potential attacker will have a very hard time connecting it through an interface it isn't even listening on! They will have to break into the system using some other way first.

Answer (score -1):

You can have server name instead of "localhost"

Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

Answer (score -2):

You can't use `localhost` unless the server and client run on the same host.

If they do run on the same host, the IP or host name the client should use depends on what the server process uses. If you want to make the server process available for the network, often you set it to listen for connections on all network interfaces. In this case it doesn't matter if the client uses localhost or the external IP address, it can connect to the server either way.

If you don't want other hosts to be able to access a server process, you can make it use the loopback interface only. This way only locally running clients can connect, and the only way they can do it is using `localhost` or a loopback IP address.

Comment: Of course it matters. If the client isn't running in the localhost it has to use an external IP address.

Comment: I was assuming that the server and client run on the same host. Qualifier added. Is the wording clear enough now?

Comment: No. 'It doesn't matter if the client uses localhost or the external IP address' remains false.

Comment: I am trying to say that if a locally running server process binds to `INADDR_ANY` it does not matter which of the locally configured IP addresses the client uses. Is this not true, or is the wording unclear?

Comment: The wording I have just quoted is incorrect unles the server is running in the localhost, and it occurs in a paragraph that starts 'if they do [run in different machines]'. You don't seem to understand your own answer.

Comment: Oh, looks like I botched the edit and ended up saying the exact opposite of what I meant. Better now?